# Can I use a container view in a prototype UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a group of collaborating controls in a cell prototype. I found that I wanted to reuse this same collaborating group outside of the table, in another view controller.

So I made a new `UIViewController` in my storyboard, moved all of the controls there and moved the interaction behavior from my `UITableViewCell` subclass to the new one. Now I just need to put a container view in the prototype cell in storyboard and hookup the embed segue. Easy enough.

What I don't know how to do though, is where the new sub view controller (my new subclass) will be instantiated, and how I can refer to it from cell subclass code? I need to pass some information from the cell's properties down to the embedded view controller. I can create an outlet for the container view in my cell, but that's for the view, not the embedded view controller.

Comment: Consider simply using a `UIView` subclass instead of a `UIViewController` subclass in this instance. Generally speaking, a `UIViewController` is used when there are many different elements that may or may not be related in the same visual space. A `UIView` is more appropriate to use for a "bunch of UI elements that will appear multiple times".

Comment: Interesting, I had actually considered the custom uiview subclass, and wondered if that would be the easier way to go. But even if I do do that, I'm still interested if one can reasonably embed a view controller in a prototype uitableviewcell.

Comment: I would suspect not. Even if you had access to the view controller when you construct the cell in order to add it as a child view controller of your container, you'd also need to be able to access it when the cell gets released back into the pool of available cells for reuse so that you could remove the view controller from your container.

Comment: Let the speculation stop. I guess I should have just hit the compile button. The compiler generates an error stating "Container views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime". Not sure what to do with this question no. You should make that your answer and get credit for it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you embed a view controller inside another view controller, the container viewController's `prepareForSegue:` method is called - here you can keep a reference to the `segue.destinationViewController`.

And therein lies the problem - `prepareForSegue:` isn't a `UITableViewCell` method, so there's would be no way to capture the child view controller.

Of course, as you've discovered - you get a compile error in any case!